# Vim: Shortcut to move to beginning of next line / end of previous line?

Tags: vim, macvim

Is there any shortcut in vim to move to the beginning of the next line or the end of the previous line? Is there any way to do it without having to use `$` or `^`?

Also, is there any way to make it so that if I hit `right` or `l` at the end of a line, it moves to the beginning of the next line? Similarly for `left` or `h` at the beginning of a line to move to the end of the preceding line? I'm using MacVim if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To move to the beginning of the next line, hit `Enter`. See `:help <CR>`.

To make `right` and `l` wrap to the beginning of the next line, add `>` and `l` to the 'whichwrap' option, e.g.,

```
:set whichwrap+=>,l
```

Similarly, to make `left` and `h` wrap to the end of the previous line, add `<` and `h` to the 'whichwrap' option, e.g.,

```
:set whichwrap+=<,h
```

See `:help 'whichwrap'`.

I don't know of a single-key shortcut to move to the end of the previous line, but with those 'whichwrap' settings, `0h` or `0left` would work, and you could possibly map either of those to some key you don't often use.

Comment: Pressing enter goes to the _beginning_ of the next line, not the end. (Which is what the OP wanted, but your answer reversed the terminology.)

Comment: @Heptite: That's what I meant. Bad fingers! Thank you for catching that. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you! Also I just figured out that to get this to work in insert mode, you can do `set whichwrap+=[,]`.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, I am not aware of any shortcut that will do what you want, but you could map it.  For example:

```
:nnoremap <c-p> k$
:nnoremap <c-n> j0
```

For your second question, look at "`:help 'whichwrap'`" (with the single quotes as part of the command).

Answer (score 1):

`+`/`-` let you move up and down on the start of every line. `$` will go to the end of line, and you'll stick there with `k`/`j`.

Comment: The OP knows about ```$``` (and ```^```) and said that he does not want to use them.

Comment: good point, -/+ still stands though